Separability of discontinuous functions.
Assume $f(x_{1}, ...x_{n})$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). If $f$ is discontinuous everywhere in an open (possibly convex) set $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$, what are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions for $f$ to be separable as a product of functions  $f=f_{1}(x_{1})...f_{n}(x_{n})$ in $D$?
All the results I can find about the separability of functions require continuity or differentiability. (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2008.02.007, https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1985.11971639)
